# Can an include file call a function from another include file?

Tags: java, jsp, include

I am new to working with jsp. 
The scenario is that *all* of the jsp pages will *always* have **include file A**. Some of these pages will need to call functions from **include file B**. My question is, can I call a function from **include file A** from functions inside **include file B**?

Wikipedia says:

> It is as if the contents of the
>   included file were pasted directly
>   into the original file.

This makes me think that this is allowed although I am not sure if this is a good practice or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely call a function in include file A from include file B.

You may wish to consider using EL/JSTL rather than scriptlets.